# Javascript - switch case - reactjs bug?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a data json looking like this.

```
var config = [{
  "craft-breweries": {
    "count": 5,
    "latest": "The Wimbledon Brewery Company Limited",
    "data": [{
      "title": "Belleville Brewing Company",
      "start": 2013
    }, {
      "title": "Kew Brewery",
      "start": 2015
    }, {
      "title": "Laines Brewery (Four Thieves)",
      "start": 2015
    }, {
      "title": "Sultan Brewery",
      "start": 2015
    }, {
      "title": "The Wimbledon Brewery Company Limited",
      "start": 2015
    }]
  },
  "farmer-markets": {
    "count": 5
  },
  "pie-markets": {
    "count": 8
  }
 }];
```

-- I am trying to dynamically append components if the key exists.

So a function called getLayers is called. It loops through the json -- but the switch case appears to satisfy keys of the loop?

Like case: "famers-markets"

satisfy's "farmer-markets" and "pie-markets"? Is it because the switch case doesn't like the hypen?

```
getLayers: function(data){
      var items = [];
      var j = 0;
      for (var layer in data) {
          console.log("layer------->", layer);

          switch (layer) {
            case 'craft-breweries':
              console.log("craft-breweries");
              items.push(<CraftBreweries key={j} config={config[0]["craft-breweries"]} />);
            case 'farmer-markets':
              console.log("farmer-markets");
              items.push(<FarmerMarket key={j} config={config[0]["farmer-markets"]} />);
            case 'pie-markets':
              console.log("pie-markets");
              items.push(<PieMarket key={j} config={config[0]["pie-markets"]} />);  
          }

          console.log("j", j);
          j++;

      }

      console.log("items", items);
      return items;      
    }
```

---

full piece

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
//import App from './App';
import './index.css';



var config = [{
  "craft-breweries": {
    "count": 5,
    "latest": "The Wimbledon Brewery Company Limited",
    "data": [{
      "title": "Belleville Brewing Company",
      "start": 2013
    }, {
      "title": "Kew Brewery",
      "start": 2015
    }, {
      "title": "Laines Brewery (Four Thieves)",
      "start": 2015
    }, {
      "title": "Sultan Brewery",
      "start": 2015
    }, {
      "title": "The Wimbledon Brewery Company Limited",
      "start": 2015
    }]
  },
  "farmer-markets": {
    "count": 5
  },
  "pie-markets": {
    "count": 8
  }
 }];


var MultipleComponents = React.createClass({


    getLayers: function(data){
      var items = [];
      var j = 0;
      for (var layer in data) {
          console.log("layer------->", layer);

          switch (layer) {
            case 'craft-breweries':
              console.log("craftbreweries");
              items.push(<CraftBreweries key={j} config={config[0]["craft-breweries"]} />);
            case 'farmer-markets':
              console.log("farmermarkets");
              items.push(<FarmerMarket key={j} config={config[0]["farmer-markets"]} />);
            case 'pie-markets':
              console.log("piemarkets");
              items.push(<PieMarket key={j} config={config[0]["pie-markets"]} />);
            default: 

          }

          console.log("j", j);
          j++;

      }

      console.log("items", items);
      return items;      
    },


    render: function () {
       var config = this.props.config;

       console.log("config", config);

       return (
            <div className="apps">
                {this.getLayers(config[0])}
            </div>
        );
    }
});



var CraftBreweries = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function () {
        //var $this = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
        console.log("rendered div now engage d3");
        // set el height and width etc.
    },
    render: function () {
        var props = this.props.config; 
        return (
            <div className="craftbreweries" data-role="craftbreweries">
                You have {props.count} number of breweries in your area. The latest one is {props.latest}.
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var FarmerMarket = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function () {
        //var $this = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
        console.log("rendered div now engage d3");
        // set el height and width etc.
    },
    render: function () {
        var props = this.props.config; 
        return (
            <div className="farmermarket" data-role="farmermarket">
                You have {props.count} number of farmer markets in your area.
            </div>
        );
    }
});


var PieMarket = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function () {
        //var $this = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
        console.log("rendered div now engage d3");
        // set el height and width etc.
    },
    render: function () {
        var props = this.props.config; 
        return (
            <div className="piemarket" data-role="piemarket">
                You have {props.count} number of pie markets in your area.
            </div>
        );
    }
});


ReactDOM.render(
    <MultipleComponents config={config} />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: surely - this is like a better way than writing a bunch of if else if statements?

Comment: If that `config` object is inded what you receive as `data` in the second piece of code, then it's not a bug. You are iterating over the _array_ not the object within.

Comment: it shouldn't be -- because I push it in as config[0]

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the 'break' statements. switch-case is not a if-else functionality, it will continue until it finds a break or ends. As for your example, it will go in to 'farmers-market' and since there's no break statement, it will contiune to 'pie-markets' as well. Your switch-case should read:

```
getLayers: function(data){
  var items = [];
  var j = 0;
  for (var layer in data) {
      console.log("layer------->", layer);

      switch (layer) {
        case 'craft-breweries':
          console.log("craft-breweries");
          items.push(<CraftBreweries key={j} config={config[0]["craft-breweries"]} />);
          break;
        case 'farmer-markets':
          console.log("farmer-markets");
          items.push(<FarmerMarket key={j} config={config[0]["farmer-markets"]} />);
          break;
        case 'pie-markets':
          console.log("pie-markets");
          items.push(<PieMarket key={j} config={config[0]["pie-markets"]} />);  
          break;
        default:
          console.log("no matches found for layer:", layer);
          break;

      }

      console.log("j", j);
      j++;

  }

  console.log("items", items);
  return items;      
}
```

Comment: Glad to be of service :)

Comment: While we are on the topic - what is the best way to fetch the json and then get it working here?

Comment: How do I serve the json to react in the first place - in this kind of control config data method

Comment: I'm not an advanced React user (yet), but I think I would have gone with the componentDidMount method in the lifecycle

Comment: Since its the first piece -- would be a component BEFORE mount?

Comment: -- George - you were right - it is -- got to push the source to it first, then during a component Did mount smack it into initial obj -- https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html